# Media Player Classic Libraries on my windows form project

Tags: c#, .net, media-player

I am developing an application which will act as a video player, but the videos embedded in my software will of be several different formats avi, mp4, flv etc ... and for that reason I do not want to use windows media player, I would like something more complete like media player classic, there are libraries of mpc? or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm partial to [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/developers/). It plays just about everything and is easy to use. They have several means of utilizing their libraries. Easiest on a .NET form is their ActiveX control.

One step better is [VLC DotNet on codeplex](https://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/)... they've done all the dirty work and it performs well.